Express how to disable parsing json?
I would like to get json endpoint body as raw buffer not as parsed json, I tried this:
webhookApp.use(express.raw({type: "*/*"})); and also webhookApp.use(express.raw({type: "application/json"})); and also use it on handler like:
webhookApp.post(
  "/",
  express.raw({type: "*/*"}),

or
webhookApp.post(
  "/",
  express.raw({type: "application/json"}),

I also tried variations with express.text() with no avail.
I verified that there is 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',.
req.body is parsed json, I noticed that regardless if I use express.raw there is always req.rawBody on req object but I can't access it since I'm using type script, well probably yes, using typings, but still curious if there is possibility to get string or buffer on req.body.
Thank you

to disables json only accepting arrays and objects, when disable will accept anything JSON.parse accepts. I think adding jsonStrings would be perfect to disable it.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

thank you for your response, but I think I don't understand, where should I add jsonStrings? Why is important what JSON.parse accepts when I want to disable it?
